# Printing pdf file without file preview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

l am having trouble finding out how to make an android app that will print certain PDF file on one button click without having to preview it or select printer.

```
public void Print(Stream inputStream, string fileName)
    {
        if (inputStream.CanSeek)
            //Reset the position of PDF document stream to be printed
            inputStream.Position = 0;
        //Create a new file in the Personal folder with the given name
        string createdFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName);
        //Save the stream to the created file
        using (var dest = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(createdFilePath))
            inputStream.CopyTo(dest);
        string filePath = createdFilePath;
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.PrintService);
        PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new CustomPrintDocumentAdapter(filePath);
        //Print with null PrintAttributes

        printManager.Print(fileName, pda, null);
    }
```

Comment: Adding what you had tried, till now will help in answering your question

Comment: Check the answers in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/171834/print-pdf-file-using-xamarin-forms) may help. There is also a link about Printing PDF’S and Images in Xamarin.Forms.